# EXCEL comparing 2 id columns for new entries

Tags: excel, compare, vlookup

I know it is a pretty basic procedure, but I am looking for a cleaner way to accomplish it.
I have two lists each one with an **ID** and a **Name** column and I would like to **compare** the two unique ID columns **and display the new entries** (the differences between the two) by their corresponding Name. Note that the IDs between the two columns can be randomly placed (eg. id=1 might be in row 23 in the first list whilst 67 in the second), also columns are not predefined in length so it would be best if the length of the list was automatically calculated.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `cleaner way to accomplish it. ` From what? Did you miss to include the tried version?

Comment: Is VBA ok, or you would prefer to do it with formulas? Do you have Excel 365 and XLOOKUP?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Both are fine although I do use formulas for the most part. I have the 2021 version with the XLOOKUP as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say columns A and B hold the *ID* and *Name* of the first list and similarly, columns D and E hold the *ID* and *Name* of the second list. Applying

```
=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1, $D:$D, 1, FALSE), "") = "", A1 & " - " & B1, "")
```

to each entry in the first list (A1 and B1 correspond to the first entry), checks if each *ID* in first list is present in the second list, and shows the entries that are unique to first list.

Similarly,

```
=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D1, $A:$A, 1, FALSE), "") = "", D1 & " - " & E1, "")
```

checks if each *ID* in the second list is present in the first one, and shows the entries that are unique to the second list.

Answer (score 0):

This code searches the two columns `A and D` for difference and fill the target sheet with the result which includes the `Address` of the impair ID.

Set

TARGETWS to the result sheet name

TARGET to the result table top left cell address.

```vb
Sub twocolumnsearch()
Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range
Dim diffcoll() As String
Const TARGETWS = "TWS"
Const TARGET = "A1"

Set col1 = Range("A1:B1")
Set col2 = Range("D1:E1")
col1row = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
col2row = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Set col1 = col1.Resize(col1row)
Set col2 = col2.Resize(col2row)
differ = -1
For i = 2 To col1row
    Set found = col2.find(col1(1).Offset(i - 1, 0))
    If found Is Nothing Then
        differ = differ + 1
        ReDim Preserve diffcoll(2, differ)
        diffcoll(1, differ) = col1(1).Offset(i - 1, 1).value
        diffcoll(0, differ) = col1(1).Offset(i - 1, 0).value
        diffcoll(2, differ) = col1(1).Offset(i - 1, 0).Address
    End If
Next i
For i = 2 To col2row
    Set found = col1.find(col2(1).Offset(i - 1, 0))
    If found Is Nothing Then
        differ = differ + 1
        ReDim Preserve diffcoll(2, differ)
        diffcoll(1, differ) = col2(1).Offset(i - 1, 1).value
        diffcoll(0, differ) = col2(1).Offset(i - 1, 0).value
        diffcoll(2, differ) = col2(1).Offset(i - 1, 0).Address
    End If
Next i
Worksheets(TARGETWS).Cells.Clear
Worksheets(TARGETWS).Range(TARGET, Worksheets(TARGETWS).Range(TARGET).Offset(0, 2)) = Array("ID", "NAME", "ADDRESS")
Worksheets(TARGETWS).Range(Worksheets(TARGETWS).Range(TARGET).Offset(1, 0), Worksheets(TARGETWS).Range(TARGET).Offset(differ + 1, 2)).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(diffcoll)
End Sub
```

The sheet where the tested data are must be the ActiveSheet when the code is launched.

The source and the result sheets.

[image: Result of code]